# sort data from mysql table using php

Tags: php, html, css

Can you help me how to sort my data from MySQL table ?

I want to sort is by using the table head :

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $valueTosearch = $_POST['searchvalue'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE CONCAT(`id`, `name`, `gender`, `user_group`, `date_registered`) LIKE '%".$valueTosearch."%'";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    } else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `admin`";
        $search_result = filterTable($query);
    }

    function filterTable($query)
    {
        include('config/dbconnect.php');
        $filter_result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        return $filter_result;
    }
?>

<form method='post' action=''>
    <div><input type = 'text' name = 'searchvalue' placeholder="search by name">
        <span>
            <div style='margin-bottom:3px; margin-top:3px'>
                <input id='gradient' class='search-btn' type = 'hidden' name = 'search' value = 'search'>
            </div>
        </span>
        <div style="height: auto">
            <table id='responsive_table'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"><a href="sort">name</a></th>
                        <th scope="col"><a href="sort">sex</a></th>
                        <th scope="col"><a href="sort">user group</a></th>
                        <th scope="col"><a href="sort">date register</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)): ?>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td scope="row" data-label='name'><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='sex'><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='user group'><?php echo $row['user_group']; ?></td>
                        <td data-label='date register'><?php echo $row['date_registered']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You mean, you are looking for something like this: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html ?

Comment: Could you use JQuery?

Comment: exactly @Twinfriends

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use **order by** clause:

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column;

[Order By Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Also not what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can modified your query as below for sorting:

```
sql > select * from <table name> order by <column name>;
```

default sorting is ascending order  else for descending you can do like

```
sql > select * from <table name> order by <column name> desc;
```

Comment: Its not what he's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you could use JQuery, it's very simple, you have just to add the following javascript code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#responsive_table").DataTable({
      ordering: true,
      searching: true
    });
});
```

for a complete example see the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
      <script>
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#responsive_table").DataTable({
              ordering: true,
              searching: true
            });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method='post' action=''>
                <div style="height: auto">
                <table id='responsive_table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">name</th>
                            <th scope="col">sex</th>
                            <th scope="col">user group</th>
                            <th scope="col">date register</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td scope="row" data-label='name'>HERE</td>
                            <td data-label='sex'>Your</td>
                            <td data-label='user group'>data</td>
                            <td data-label='date register'>loaded</td>
                        </tr>
                      <tr>
                            <td scope="row" data-label='name'>via</td>
                            <td data-label='sex'>PHP</td>
                            <td data-label='user group'>loop</td>
                            <td data-label='date register'>bye</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </div>
            </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yay. The only answer that is correct and really helps TO... and no upvotes for you. But the other two guys recive upvotes with answers that nobody cares about. Whats wrong today? At least, nice answer Alessandro. You're the only one who understood this question. Think the other ones just read the title.

Comment: Thanks @Twinfriends